# Match 'pattern' from one file to header's name in another (R, Unix)

Tags: r, regex, header

I have two large files, and I am trying to match information from the first column of the file_1, to the header of the file_2. There is small detail, the header of the file_2 has some information in the beginning, which is varies from column to column, but in the end it has the pattern match. Basically, i have to find where 'pattern' from file_1 is present in the end of the column's name of file 2 and to output data.frame with this information.
Please see below how files look like:

```
**file_1**  dim (757*3) the first column of the file_1 contains patterns
10001-101A3  a   t
10008-101B6  b   g
10235-104A1  c   h
-            -   -
-            -   -
etc...

**file_2** dim (4120*1079)
blabla.10001.101A3   blbl.2348.101B6 trsdr.1111.111D2 gfder.10008.101B6  ....
12                         1223           544               -              -
132                         23           3564               -              -
14                         223           33               -              -
162                         13           344               -              -


**Desired output file-3:** I assume that the output size will be 4120*757
blabla.10001.101A3   gfder.10008.101B6  ....
12                    -              -
132                   -              -
14                    -              -
162                    -              -
```

I am trying to get the output with R (below is my script), but I would also like to learn how I can do it in Unix (I guess -awk and  -grep can help to solve this problem).

here is my R script:

```
table1=read.table("file2.tsv.gz", quote=NULL, sep='\t', header=T, fill=T)
table2=read.table("file1.txt", quote=NULL, sep='\t', header=T, fill=T)
    # dim(table1 4120 * 1079)   -> need to reduce amount of columns to 757
    # dim(table2 757 * 3)

###### the header in table1 has following view 10001.101A3, thus we need to substitute '-' to '.' in pattern
### What to do:
### 1) Use gsub() function to substitute '-' by '.' 
### 2) Use gsub() function to remove space in the end of string ' ' by ''
### 3) Find modified pattern in the end of column's name
### 4) Apply to the entire table

pattern=table2[,1]            # '10001-101A3 '  '10008-101B6 ' 
for (x in pattern)  {
    ptn=gsub('-','.',x)
    ptn1=gsub(' ','',ptn)            # pattern to be matched'
                                     # '10001.101A3'  '10008.101B6' 

    find_match=table1[,(grepl('^.+ptn1$', header))]   
    final_tb=table1[,find_match]
}
```

I think that the problem is with data representation of ptn1 in grepl() function, because when i insert 10001.101A3 instead of ptn1 I get the answer for one run, but clearly I need to loop over it.

I also tried get(ptn1), but still couldn't make it work.

I would appreciate your comments and also any ideas how this can be don in Unix (I am very basic user of Unix, thus can't implement this task at the moment).

######################## trail on small data

```
df=data.frame(aa24.12a,dda43.23s,fds24.12a,sdf24.112f)
```

z=c('24-12a ','43-23s ')     # pattern

```
aa24.12a fds24.12a aa24.12a.1 fds24.12a.1
1        2        34          2          34
2        3         2          3           2
3        4         1          4           1
4       56         3         56           3
5        3         5          3           5


header=colnames(df)
for (x in z){
     ptn=gsub('-','.',x)
     ptn1=gsub(' ','',ptn)# correct pattern 

     find_match=grep('^.+24.12a$', header)# find match of pattern in header
     tbl=df[,find_match]
}
> tbl
  aa24.12a fds24.12a
1        2        34
2        3         2
3        4         1
4       56         3
5        3         5
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you N8TRO, for you solution and prompt reply.

My own solution to the question I asked:

```
# Modify pattern z=('24-12a','43-23s')
ptn=gsub('-','.',z)
ptn1=gsub(' ','',ptn)
# so no it looks like '24.12a' '34.23s'

i=1        
# create empty vector
df2=c()        
# Iterate:
# first loop through column names of data frame 
# second loop goes through vector's value
# grepl -> searches for matches
# condition, ==TRUE
# if so: append to the empty vector, values in the vector will be column numbers 

for (x in colnames(df)){
    for (y in ptn1){
        e=grepl(y,x)
            if (e==TRUE){
                df2=append(df2,i)
        }
    }
    i=i+1
}
```

desired_output =df[, df2]

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's something more concise, but using a quick hack one-liner:

```
read.table(text=
"**file_1**  dim (757*3) the first column of the file_1 contains patterns
10001-101A3  a   t
10008-101B6  b   g
10235-104A1  c   h", 
comment.char="*") -> dat1

read.table(text="
**file_2** dim (4120*1079)
blabla.10001.101A3   blbl.2348.101B6 trsdr.1111.111D2 gfder.10008.101B6  ....
12                         1223           544               -              -
132                         23           3564               -              -
14                         223           33               -              -
162                         13           344               -              -", 
comment.char="*", header=TRUE) -> dat2


dat2[,unlist(sapply(dat1[,1], function(x) grep(sub(x, pattern="-", replacement="."), colnames(dat2))))]

#  blabla.10001.101A3 gfder.10008.101B6
#1                 12                 -
#2                132                 -
#3                 14                 -
#4                162                 -
```